# Почему list.remove() неправильно удаляет элементы в цикле?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы, python-faq

В основном я занимаюсь разработкой на C/C++, но появилась задача написания приложения на Python-3 и я столкнулся с некоторым непониманием работы интерпретатора.

Я допустил ошибку и некоторое время не замечал ее, так как Python сделал все "почти" правильно. Задача состояла в удалении из списка N/2 значений, где N - общее их количество.

Простой пример описывающий ситуацию:

```py
array = []

for i in range(10):
    array.append(i)
# array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

i = 0
for item in array:
    if i < len(array)/2:
        array.remove(item)

# array [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Как вы заметили, я не инкрементирую переменную `i` во втором цикле, но интерпретатор каким то образом все равно удаляет из массива нулевой и каждый четный элемент.

Собственно вопрос, как это работает?

Comment: Разобрался, тут выходит что срабатывает сдвиг индекса item и по этому перескакивает.

Comment: Не стоит удалять вопрос: он скорее всего поможет и другим людям тоже

Comment: @Culit если разобрались, то хорошо бы не удалять вопрос, а ответить самому. В будущем может помочь другим участникам. Ну, если не хотите отвечать сами, то хотя бы не удаляйте вопросы, чтобы другие участники могли ответить (:

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Всё просто - вы модифицируете итерируемый массив

> Step 1: array=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] index = 0 array[index] = 0
>   Удаляется 0.
>   Step 2: array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] index = 1 array[index] = 2
>   Удаляется 2.
>   Step 3: array=[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] index = 2 array[index] = 4
>   Удаляется 4.

И так далее.

Этот цикл аналогичен циклу:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) vec.erase(vec.begin() + i);
```

Модификация массива меняет последовательность итерируемых элементов.

---

*Удалить же половину элементов массива можно просто создав новый срез:*

```
array = array[len(array)//2:] # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Comment: `array = array[len(array)//2:]  # [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

Comment: @gil9red. действительно)

Comment: `array[::2] --> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]; array[1::2] --> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

Comment: @mkkik жесть синтаксис конечно)

Comment: @yolosora довольно классическая читаемая индексация `[start : stop : step]`, никой жести.

Comment: @mkkik если нужно знать заранее как это разбирать, то это не особо подходит под определение "читаемый" :) Для меня это выглядело как набор рандомных символов в обращении к элементу массива по индексу.

Comment: @yolosora, это вопрос опыта. Для кого-то и `for(i=0;i<n;++i);` набор рандомных символов.

Answer (score 5):

Решил дополнить принятый ответ небольшой демонстрацией.

Предположим у нас есть дав списка:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3]
to_drop = [1, 3]
```

и нам нужно удалить из списка `lst` все элементы, которые встречаются в списке `to_drop` и мы делаем это в цикле при помощи метода [list.remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
for x in lst:
    if x in to_drop:
        lst.remove(x)
print(lst)
# вывод [1, 2]
```

чтобы понять почему единица не удалилась, можно добавить в цикл вывод отладочной информации:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3]
to_drop = [1, 3]

for i,x in enumerate(lst):
    print(f"обрабатываем элемент [{x}] с индексом [{i}]")
    if x in to_drop:
        lst.remove(x)
    print(lst)
```

вывод на экран:

```
обрабатываем элемент [1] с индексом [0] -> [1, 2, 3]
обрабатываем элемент [2] с индексом [1] -> [1, 2, 3]
обрабатываем элемент [3] с индексом [2] -> [1, 2]
```

как видно из вывода на второй итерации цикла - мы обращаемся к элементу измененного списка `lst` с индексом `1`. Т.к. мы удалили первую единицу на первом шаге цикла, теперь `lst = [1, 2, 3]` и элементом с индексом `1` уже стала двойка. Таким образом переменная итерирования `x` перескочила на одну (удаленную) позицию. Поэтому часто советуют не изменять список, по которому вы проходите циклом.

---

> Как это сделать правильно?

Одним из вариантов будет обработка списка задом-наперед - в этом случае переменная итерирования будет перескакивать уже удаленные элементы:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3]
to_drop = [1, 3]

for i,x in enumerate(lst[::-1]):
    if x in to_drop:
        lst.remove(x)
    print(f"обрабатываем элемент [{x}] с индексом [{i}] -> {lst[::-1]}")
```

вывод:

```
обрабатываем элемент [3] с индексом [0] -> [2, 1, 1]
обрабатываем элемент [2] с индексом [1] -> [2, 1, 1]
обрабатываем элемент [1] с индексом [2] -> [2, 1]
обрабатываем элемент [1] с индексом [3] -> [2]
```

Но наиболее правильно - просто создать новый список:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 3]
to_drop = [1, 3]

res = [x for x in lst if x not in to_drop]
print(res)
```

вывод:

```
[2]
```