# Цикл перескакивает шаг

Tags: python, парсер, циклы

столкнулся с проблемой при написании парсера. Цикл делает один шаг, а следующий перескакивает, проблема происходит только после сохранения результатов в список, если просто выводить результаты проблема исчезает. Вот три функции, первая это ввод ключевых слов, вторая это запись результатов в txt файл(они обе рабочие), проблема в третьей функции.   Надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

find_items = []
find_links = []
searching_list = []
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36'
}
items = [
    "http://gymnaz1-murm.ru/",
    "http://2gimn51.ru/",
    "http://gym3murmansk.ucoz.ru/publ/?page1",
    "http://gimn5.murm.eduru.ru/news",
    "http://gymn6.com.ru/",
    "http://gim7.murm.eduru.ru/",
    "http://www.gimnazia8.ru/",
    "https://mml.ucoz.org/",
    "http://www.mplmurmansk.ru/",
    "http://murmanprg24.ucoz.ru/",
    "http://prog40.ru/novosti",
]

def input_keywords():
    print("Для выхода из парсера введите: exit")
    print("Для перехода к парсингу введите: next \n")
    
    searching_list.clear()

    while True:    
        searching_text = input('Введите ключевое слово или словосочетание для поиска: ')
        
        if searching_text.lower() == 'next':
            break               
        elif searching_text == ':)':
            print('(-_-)')
        if searching_text.lower() == 'exit':
            exit("Досвидания!")           

        searching_list.append(searching_text) 
        
        print(f'Текущий список слов для поиска: {searching_list}\n\n') 
 

def save_file_txt(find_items, items, find_links):

    not_found_f = open(f'{searching_list[0]}_не_найдено.txt', "a")           
    found_f = open(f'{searching_list[0]}_найдено.txt', "a") 
    found_f_links = open(f'{searching_list[0]}_ссылки.txt', "a")

    for i in find_items:         
        found_f.write(i + '\n')
    for i in items:
        not_found_f.write(i + '\n')
    for i in find_links:
        found_f_links.write(i + '\n')
        
    found_f.close()
    not_found_f.close() 
    found_f_links.close()


def parse():
    for item in items:
        req = requests.get(item, headers=headers)
        src = req.text
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
        hrefs = soup.find_all('a')
        site_text = soup.get_text().lower()
        
        break_flag = False
        for href in hrefs:
            href_text = href.get_text().lower()           
            for keyword in searching_list:
                if keyword in href_text:
                    break_flag = True
                    print(item)
                    find_links.append(href.get('href'))
                    find_items.append(item)
                    items.remove(item)
                    break
                elif break_flag == False and href == hrefs[-1] and keyword in site_text:
                    break_flag = True
                    print(item)
                    find_links.append(item)
                    find_items.append(item)
                    items.remove(item)
                    break
                               
            if break_flag:
                break
            
    save_file_txt(find_items, items, find_links)

input_keywords()
parse()
```

Comment: Для выхода из парсера введите: exit
Для перехода к парсингу введите: next 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module2>", line 93, in <module>
  File "<module2>", line 25, in input_keywords
NameError: name 'searching_list' is not defined

Comment: Ваш пример не запускается

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл добавить список)

Comment: Исправьте все ошибки!!!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему list.remove() неправильно удаляет элементы в цикле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992441/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-list-remove-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5) В цикле по коллекции (у вас items) нельзя удалять элементы (`items.remove(item)`).

Comment: Исправил все ошибки

Comment: `for item in items:` ... `items.remove` - тут проблема, попробуйте `for item in items.copy():`, возможно этого будет достаточно. Но вопрос в любом случае дубликат.

Comment: CrazyElf, спасибо ваш вариант помог, сначала хотел записывать не найденные элементы в другой список при помощи условия, но ваш вариант гораздо лучше. Премного благодарен.