# Удаление элементов из списка через цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

**Только недавно начал изучать питон и вот столкнулся с первыми проблемами**

**Вот само задание**

using loop remove all x occurences in the above list

hint -> think what condition you need to specify for loop break

**А вот как я попытался его решить**

```
my_list = [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 'x', 'x']


for i in my_list:
  if i == 'x':
    my_list.remove(i)

print(my_list)
```

**Не могу понять, почему после компиляции в ответе остаётся 'x'**

```
[1, 2, 3, 'x']
```

Comment: Неоднократно завался вопрос. дубликат вопроса: [Почему list.remove() неправильно удаляет элементы в цикле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/992441/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-list-remove-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 0):

Удаление меняет количество элементов и это имеет значение, если перебор идет по порядку

В вашем случае решением будет перебор с конца:

```
my_list = [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 'x', 'x']
for i in reversed(my_list):
    if i == 'x':
        my_list.remove(i)
print(my_list)
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Еще можно создать новый список, исключая элемент:

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if x != 'x']
```

Comment: Причем тут reversed, вы просто итерируете по другому списку. можно my_list[:]

Comment: @splash58, как это "по-другому"?

Comment: reversed возвращает список и цикл идет по нему

Comment: @splash58, а чем это противоречит заданию "using loop remove all x occurences in the above list"? За что минус-то за ответ?

Comment: за объяснение - про перебор с конца. код, может, и  рабочий

Comment: @splash58, ясно, спасибо. Как-то совсем вы жестко:-) На основной-то вопрос "Не могу понять, почему после компиляции в ответе остаётся 'x'" отвечено. Я всё же `+` поставлю за ответ. И да, конечно, лучше всего применять ваш [:] - официально рекомендованный способ.

Comment: @Сергей, я плохо объясняю. вот что делает этот код: `j = my_list.count('x'); for i in range(j): my_list.remove('x')` какое отношение к перебору с конца это имеет?

Comment: @splash58, я понял и первое ваше объяснение, спасибо. Оно нормальное.

Comment: @splash58, `Функция reversed() возвращает обратный итератор, то есть возвращает итератор, который перебирает элементы оригинала в обратном порядке. Функция reversed() не создает копию и не изменяет оригинал последовательности.`: https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-reversed/ А `[:]` вернет копию объекта

Answer (score 0):

Вы модифицируете последовательность, с которой работает итератор. В результате, он прекращает нормально работать. Вам нужно или идти с конца в таком случае или создать копию списка, как рекомендует официальное руководство Python при необходимости модификации итерируемых последовательностей: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

С копией:

```
my_list = [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 'x', 'x']


for i in my_list[:]:
  if i == 'x':
    my_list.remove(i)

print(my_list)
```

С проходом с конца:

```
my_list = [1, 'x', 2, 'x', 3, 'x', 'x']


for i in range (len(my_list) -1, -1, -1):
    if my_list[i] == 'x':
        del my_list[i]

print(my_list)
```

Кстати, следующую ошибку рекомендую иссследовать самому с помощью отладчика. Я сам использую PyCharm. Вот здесь очень простая и короткая рекомендация по отладке в моём ответе на другой вопрос: [Ошибка в коде генерации пароля. Просьба помочь найти причину, дать пояснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1423731/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/1423738#1423738)

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)  Количество ответов с плюсами не ограничено, но принять можно только один.